# Having Trouble Verifying Twitch EventSub Signature

Tags: python-2.7, webhooks, sha256, twitch

So I've been building my own advanced scripts for Streamlabs Chatbot for a while now and I've gotten to the point where I need to access Twitch webhooks via EventSub. The problem I'm running into is for the life of me I can't figure out how to verify the signature that is returned.

The Twitch documents (https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/eventsub#verify-a-signature) says:

> The signature uses HMAC-SHA256. The HMAC key is your subscription’s secret. The HMAC message is the concatenation of the Twitch-Eventsub-Message-Id header, the Twitch-Eventsub-Message-Timestamp header, and the raw bytes of the request body.

It then gives some pseudocode to use:

```
hmac_message = headers['Twitch-Eventsub-Message-Id'] + headers['Twitch-Eventsub-Message-Timestamp'] + request.body
signature = hmac_sha256(webhook_secret, hmac_message)
expected_signature_header = 'sha256=' + signature.hex()

if headers['Twitch-Eventsub-Message-Signature'] != expected_signature_header:
    return 403
```

This code would be great except I have no idea what the `hmac_sha256()` function is supposed to be. My IDE doesn't recognize it.

I've tried many other methods of calculating the signature but every time I get an incorrectly computed signature. So basically I just need to actually figure out how to calculate the Twitch signature using sha256 hash.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the twitch documentation what they provided as an example is pseudo code, not actual code to run.

This post has an example of verify signature, which should be enough for you to figure this out.

https://discuss.dev.twitch.tv/t/verifying-signature-mismatch-python-and-i-dont-know-why/32112

If you still can't figure it out let me know and i'll post an example for you.

Edit: Adding Example for python

The webhook secret should be an ENV variable you set when you originally created the twitch subscription. The event_body, is the json body twitch sends, it should be in a key called 'body'

```
def valid_signature(headers, event_body):
    message_id = headers['twitch-eventsub-message-id']
    message_timestamp = headers['twitch-eventsub-message-timestamp']
    message_signature = headers['twitch-eventsub-message-signature']

    hmac_message = message_id + message_timestamp + event_body

    key = bytes(webhook_secret, 'utf-8')
    data = bytes(hmac_message, 'utf-8')

    signature = hmac.new(key, data, hashlib.sha256)

    expected_signature_header = 'sha256=' + signature.hexdigest()

    logger.info(f'Expected: {expected_signature_header}')
    logger.info(f'Actual: {message_signature}')

    if message_signature != expected_signature_header:
        return False

    return True
```

Comment: Can you please add an example? I am trying to verify the signature in Java but I always get a different signature of what twitch sends

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add another example, for python users using FastAPI:

```py
async def verify_eventsub_headers(request: Request) -> bool:
    id = request.headers.get('twitch-eventsub-message-id')
    timestamp = request.headers.get('twitch-eventsub-message-timestamp')
    event_body = await request.body()
    text = bytes.decode(event_body, 'utf-8')

    def get_signature(hmac_message: str) -> str:
        key = bytes("SECRET_WHEN_CREATING_THE_WEBHOOK", 'utf-8')
        data = bytes(hmac_message, 'utf-8')
        signature = hmac.new(key, data, hashlib.sha256)

        return 'sha256=' + signature.hexdigest()

    return request.headers.get('twitch-eventsub-message-signature') != get_signature(id + timestamp + text)
```